# Evaluate a definite double integral of the integrand of the gaussian integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have to solve this by changing the order of integration,

$$\int_0^4 \int_\frac y4^2 e^{-x^2} \,dx\, dy$$

and I got this far,

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{4x} e^{-x^2}\, dy\, dx$$

but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something.

Help please?

Comment: I thought the bounds changed if I went up to 2?

Comment: What I meant (in a now deleted comment) is that for example the point $(x,y)=(2,4)$ is in the original region of integration  (well, a corner of it) but is missing from the second, because $x$ is constrained to $[0,1]$.

Comment: So I need another integral for the missing corner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is that you forgot to draw a picture! The integral
$$
I=\int_{y=0}^4\int_{x=y/4}^2e^{-x^2}\,dx\,dy
$$
specifies that we are to integrate $f(x,y)=e^{-x^2}$ over the region $D$ that looks like the one below.

[image]

Your second integral is missing the part with $x>1$. It is best to split this into two parts, so
$$
I=\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^{4x}e^{-x^2}\,dy\,dx+
\int_{x=1}^2\int_{y=0}^4 e^{-x^2} \,dy\,dx.
$$
The point is that $y$ may never exceed $4$, so when $x>1$, the range of $y$ is constant $[0,4]$.

Here the first integral can be evaluated explicitly - see Przemysław's answer. You need a table for the numerical value of the second, but it can be done, because the $y$-integration is still simple. It is probably ok to write the value of the second integral in terms of the error function.

Comment: Oh, you are vigilant! I was so sure that the intention in this exercise is changing a function to an easy-integrable one, that I didn't check the region. Well, I am still thinking that it is the intention, but the contants 4 and 1/4 were swapped in formulation. :-)

Comment: @DylanDang thanks for spotting the missing integrand!

Answer (score 1):

Good. The inner integral in equal to
$$
\int_0^{4x} e^{-x^2}\, dy=4xe^{-x^2}
$$
and is easy integrable by $x$.